# How to read json in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following json:

```
{
"a1": [
"b1","b2"
],
"a2": [
"c1","c2","c3"
]
}
```

In my controller i get json with the following code:

```
$.getJSON('tk.json', function(data) {
$scope.$apply(function(){
$scope.modelData = data;
});
});
```

I watch a variable and when it changes, i want to get the specific list from json. For example:

```
$scope
.$watch(
'value1',
function() {
if ($scope.value1 != null)           
{                                                                         
var tempValue = $scope.value1;
$scope.data = $scope.modelData.temValue;           
console.log($scope.data);//undefined
}
});
```

If value is a1 i want the 
    list=["b1","b2"].
With the following 
    $scope.data = $scope.modelData.temValue; 
i get value undefined for $scop.data.

How can i read json in order to find the right list?
Thank you

Comment: did you debug and check what the getJSON call returns in the data parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `$scope.modelData` is an object, you must access its properties in two ways:

- Directly: `$scope.modelData.a1`
- By String: `$scope.modelData['a1']`

So, as you have a variable `tempData`, and it's a String, you must use:

```
$scope.data = $scope.modelData[tempValue];
```

---

By doing `$scope.data = $scope.modelData.tempValue;` as you were, it will try to find a property named `tempValue` inside the `$scope.modelData` variable, and that property doesn't exist.

That's why your console is logging `undefined`.

Comment: @StavrosKouris if my answer was useful for you, please, click on the arrow to upvote it, and click on the `V` to mark it as the accepted one.